# How to set cache-control header in odata4j?

Tags: odata, jax-rs, odata4j

I'm writing a RESTful service using odata4j and need to be able to set the caching header of the response.

How do I do this?
I don't seem to have access to the HttpservletResponse object.
And unlike the JAX-RS support, I can't see anything in odata4j that lets me get hold of a CacheControl object.

Thanks

Sarah

Answer (score 0):

No direct support for this as of 0.5 - however you could write a custom ContainerResponseFilter to modify the outgoing response manually.

Feel free to add a feature request on the project issue list [1], along with any detail on a proposed api if you have thoughts on how this might work.

Or, of course, a patch...  : )

Hope that helps,

- john

[1] http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/issues/list